# Store a long string on Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to save the configuration as a JSON string on the Azure Vault using this code:

```
public async Task SetSecretValueAsync(string vault, string keyName, string secretName, string value,
                                          CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName))
    {
        return;
    }

    var cred = new ManagedIdentityCredential(_managedId);

    var vaultUri = new Uri($"https://{vault}.vault.azure.net/");
    var keyClient = new KeyClient(vaultUri, cred);
    var key = (await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(keyName, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(
        false)).Value;

    var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(key.Id, cred);
    var valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
    var encryptResult = await cryptoClient.EncryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, valueBytes, cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var base64Value = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptResult.Ciphertext);

    var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, cred);
    await client.SetSecretAsync(secretName, base64Value, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I thought the maximum length of the secret value was 25KB but when I try to go over 255 characters, it gives me an exception. Is there a way to set the value for anything longer than 255 characters? It seems pretty short.

Comment: What is the exception? I've definitely stored data larger than 255 characters in KV manually and via CLI

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the problem you are having is to do with the size of the secret you are trying to store. Most likely it is the `CryptographyClient` call which is failing and you never get to the `SecretClient` call.

```
var encryptResult = await cryptoClient.EncryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, valueBytes, cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I think KeyVault only supports encrypting strings up to 255 characters in length although I can't find a source confirming it. It's probably due to the limitations of the underlying encryption algorithms being used.

Comment: Oh you're probably correct. Thanks. So any workarounds for this?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an elegant solution using keyvault - you could try to come up with a scheme that first takes chunks of the string then somehow assigns them an index and write another function to reassemble. It may be that you need to use another technology - blob storage maybe. Sorry I can't be more help,